How to remove FormControlState from FormControl values
I'm trying to create a helper function like this, to create a stream of the current value and valueChanges of an Angular FormControl
import { AbstractControl, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, defer, startWith } from 'rxjs';

export function valuesOf<V>(control: AbstractControl<V>): Observable<V> {
  return defer(() => control.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(control.value)));
}

const c = new FormControl('Alma');
valuesOf(c);

For some reason my valuesOf function returns an observable with the current type:
function valuesOf<string | FormControlState<string | null> | null>(control: AbstractControl<string | FormControlState<string | null> | null, string | FormControlState<string | null> | null>): Observable<...>

I dug into the source code, but I have no idea where that FormControlState<string | null> comes from.
Here is a reproduction
How can I prevent FormControlState<string | null> being in the type?

There is something wrong going with the forms typing here. It shouldn't return ForControlState for the value.

HA, I actually contributed to a PR to fix this :)
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/55860

We can use Exclude to remove a certain type from a union type. Here I remove FormControlState<string | null> using the below type definition.
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, FormControlState } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, defer, startWith } from 'rxjs';
export type ExcludeState<V> =  Exclude<
  V,
  FormControlState<string | null>
>;

export function valuesOf<V>(
  control: AbstractControl<ExcludeState<V>>
): Observable<ExcludeState<V>> {
  return defer(() => control.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(control.value)));
}

const c = new FormControl('Alma');
valuesOf(c);

const c1 = new FormControl(1);
valuesOf(c1);

Stackblitz Demo

While this might work, I'd consider this is a workaround, not a proper solution

@MatthieuRiegler feel free to post the proper solution

I just found out we have a PR to actually fix the typing https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/55860 :)

Yeah, this does not seem right because without the wrapper function the defer(() => control.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(control.value))) is good.

@Totati I though the wrapper function is needed. since you mentioned in the question
